# Cannot POST /express/

Tags: javascript, express

quiero hacer mi primer formulario usando express y utilizando el método de http con post y estoy recibiendo el siguiente error: Cannot POST

```
//entry point
const express = require ('express'); 
const app = express();
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.use ('/', users);
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('todo ok en el puerto 3000');
});
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json()); 

//ruta
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require ('../controllers/controller');
router.get('/register', controller.register); 
router.post('/register', controller.store); 
module.exports = router;

//controlador
const controller = {
    register: (req, res) => {
         res.render('register');
    },
    store: (req, res) => {
        let usuario = {
            nombre: req.body,
            edad: req.body,
            email: req.body,
        }
        res.send(usuario);
    }
}
module.exports = controller;

//formulario
    <form method="POST" action='/register'>
        <label for="">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">
        <br>
        <label for="">Edad</label>
        <input type="text" name="edad">
        <br>
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
```

al momento sigue sin poder ver qué esto haciendo mal pero sé que debe haber un problema entre el formulario y el controlador

¿qué puedo estar haciendo de forma incorrecta?

Comment: Pues probé tu código, solo le agregué `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` y me funciona perfectamente. Cuando le doy enviar al formulario me devuelve para atrás los datos que ingresé.

Answer (score 0):

Estas cargando tu formulario (que supongo que está en un HTML) en el servidor que estás creando? Sí no lo hiciste, el formulario no reconoce /register.

Sí no lo haz hecho, aquí te lo explico:

- En la raíz del proyecto, crea la carpeta "public".
- En el entry point, tienes que importar path (un elemento que viene con
  node, no debes instalar nada).
- También, debes colocar la siguiente línea: app.use(/ruta,
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
- Está línea lo que hace es servir en la /ruta lo que
  está en la carpeta public.
- Ahora, en el buscador, accedes a /ruta/index.html. Ahí estará el
  formulario para que puedas enviar datos al mismo servidor donde estás
  sirviendo el HTML.